# Can't figure out the error in this simple Java code

Tags: java

```
public class Test {
    class Foo {
        int frob() {
            return 7;
        }
    }

    class Bar extends Foo {
        @Override
        int frob() {
            return 8;
        }
    }

    class Baz extends Foo {
        @Override
        int frob() {
            return 9;
        }
    }

    public static int quux(Bar b) {
        return b.frob();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(quux(new Bar()));//this line gives non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fix this by declaring the nested classes as *static*, OR by instantiating *Bar* in the context of an instance of *Test*.

It fails because (the non-static) *Bar* must be instantiated in the context of an existing *Test* class instance; since *main* is static, there is no such beast.

Answer (score 3):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test test = new Test();
    System.out.println(quux(test.new Bar()));
}
```

Comment: Your answer is as good as the accepted one except he posted it a minute earlier.

Answer (score 2):

Non-static inner classes have a hidden reference to the enclosing class instance. This means you must have an instance of the enclosing class to create the inner class. You also have to use a special "new" function that correctly initializes the hidden reference to the enclosing class. For example,

```
   class Outer{   
        class Inner{
           public Inner() {
               System.out.println("Hello there.");
           }
        }

        public static void main(String args[]) {
            Outer o = new Outer();     
            Outer.Inner i = o.new Inner();
        }
    }
```